# Can I generate Toast with a static method used in many Activities?

Tags: java, android, toast

I created a class to generate `Toast`. I want it because I need to cancel a previous `Toast` when I'm showing a new one.

My doubt is that in my class I have

1. a static method
2. a `Toast` static class field

and, at the same time,  I'm passing the static method different `Context`, depending on the `Activity` in which I call the static method:`ToastUtility.generateToast(activity_context, "message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);`

This is the class:

```
public class ToastUtility {

    private static Toast myToast;

    public static void generateToast(Context context, String message, int duration){
        if(myToast != null)myToast.cancel();
        myToast = Toast.makeText(context, message, duration);
        myToast.show();
    }
}
```

I'm afraid, I didn't think about some problems that may occur when using  `static` method and field but different `Context`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Way too many down votes for a fine question.

Comment: `-5 what's wrong here ?`

Comment: Even I was shocked when open the question and see too many negative voting.

Comment: @MD I don't know

Comment: Up vote from my side for Good Question. :)

Comment: @MDP you don't need to do anything. Your logic is 100% right and fitting to your needs.

Comment: Thank everybody. I often have doubts  when using static methods and fields in a particular scenario

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can use this statement in your activity as:

```
 Utils.showToast(this, "" + model.getMessage());
```

and in Utils class you can create a method like:

```
public static void showToast(Activity activity, String message) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(activity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }
```

Comment: You might also want to wrap it inside a [Activity.runOnUiThread()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)) call to ensure that the Toast is not shown from a non-UI thread

Comment: @SpaceBison thank you for your advice; I didn't know that method. It's very interesting. Inside the run() method of the runnable class, should I put just toast.show() or should I put all the code related to the creation of the Toast. I didn't find clear directions on google

Comment: Creating a Toast instance is not a time-consuming operation, so you can both create and show it on the main thread. Also, the default gravity for Toasts is already `Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM`, you can omit setting it explicitly and use a nice clean chained call: `Toast.makeText(activity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`